# NullReferenceException when extending the ASP.NET Core InputTagHelper class without For expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to extend the buildin InputTagHelpers from ASP.NET Core, simple example

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input")]
class TestTagHelper:InputTagHelper{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
        base.Process(context,output);
    }
}
```

This should call the default input tag helper. Its working fine when the `From` attribute like `<input asp-for="SomeModelAttribute" />` but not when I have elements which aren't associated with any model attribute, like a submit button `<input type="submit" />`. In this case, I got an NullReferenceException.

According to the [source code of the helper class](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ada42ea913097f31bcbe495cf48879bfa9c5efe9/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs), it seems that the following lines causing the issue:

```
var metadata = For.Metadata;
var modelExplorer = For.ModelExplorer;
```

But the strange thing is when I use the buildin taghelper without inheritance from my class (directly `InputTagHelper`), it works, no matter if the `For` attribute is present. I need a solution for this because when I call the Process method of the base class only when For is not null, it breaks my input elements: `<input type="submit" />` is rendered as `<input />` which doesn't make sense in this place.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your TagHelper attribute to only trigger on `input` elements which have the `asp-for` attribute, and are self-closing.

This is what the `InputTagHelper` class uses by default:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
```